# cakephp 2: Pass variable from controller to element

Tags: php, controller, cakephp-2.0, element

I want to pass information from my controller into my element. What cakephp 2 function do I use prior to rendering my element so that my login_ajax element is aware of the value of $error.

This is an abbreviated version of my controller function

```
public function login($_msg=null) {

    $this->get_post('login');
    $error = false;

    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        if($this->Auth->login()) {
            // REDIRECT TO DASHBOARD
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
        } else {
            $error = true;
        }
    }

    // !! pass $error status to element here !!
    $this->set('element', 'login_ajax');
    $this->render('ajax_modal', 'ajax');
}
```

And the variable doesn't need to be named $error if that would cause a conflict, it's just an example.

Thanks

Comment: I figured it out, $this->set('error', $error); within the element the variable $error will be created with the desired value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this:
`$this->set('error',$error)` and in your element you use can use `$error`.